# How can I open image of vmplayer in virtualbox

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, vmware-player

I have installed Ubuntu in vmplayer, as the vmplayer does not support Unity of Ubuntu, I want to be able to open the image in virtualbox. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

First I assume by vmplayer you mean VMware Player?

You should be able to simply open your VMware disk (.vmdk) in VirtualBox.

*n.b. this won't work the other way around, i.e. you can't open VirtualBox disks with VMware Player.*

Comment: Yeah, just create a new virtual machine with compatible hardware (i.e. same number of processor core, chipset and disk controller) and select the vmdk as the disk image. Also, VMware Player is free software, if you can't get vbox to work, you can always install that.

Comment: I can open the vmdk by virtualbox, but I cannot enter the desktop environment of Ubuntu